# How to connect a full duplex line driver

Tags: uart, transceiver

I need to use two line drivers for the communication between two PCBs. I am currently using [MAX3081 from Analog](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX3080-MAX3089.pdf) and this is what I see in the datasheet:

[image: pin configuration and typical full-duplex operating circuit]

Image Source: [Analog - MAX3080-MAX3089 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX3080-MAX3089.pdf)

Now my doubt is about the pins Y, Z, A, B. They are:¨

- Y: Non inverting driver output
- Z: Inverting driver output
- A: Non inverting receiver input
- B: Inverting receiver input

For proper connection between the two integrated circuit (IC1 and IC2), should I cross them and  connect as following?

- Y(IC1) -> A(IC2)
- Z(IC1) -> B(IC2)
- A(IC1) -> Y(IC2)
- B(IC1) -> Z(IC2)

Or did I get it wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect them as shown in the image. Your connections are correct.

(Cross between the driver and receiver, but do not cross the non-inverting and inverting signals.)